# Android AsyncTask return the value after finishing work

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

this is my first post.
I apologize for not good English.
I have read many questions about this topic.

Writes an application that download phone numbers and message to clients from the database on the server.

```
public class Connect extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,ArrayList<CUSTOMER>>{
ArrayList<CUSTOMER> clients= new ArrayList<CUSTOMER>();
 if(type.equals("login"))
    {
    //... conection code
    while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null) {
                if (line.equals(error)) {

                    break;
                } else {

                    result += line + "\n";                        
                    String podziel = new String(line);
                    String[] tab = null;
                    tab= podziel.split(";");
                    for (int i = 0; i < tab.length; i++) {
                        Log.e("peta "+Integer.toString(i), tab[i]);
                    }
                    licznik++;
                    CUSTOMER C= new CUSTOMER(Integer.parseInt(tab[0]), tab[1], tab[2]);
                    clients.add(C);
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                    //Log.e("k "  , clients.get(0).getId()+" "+clients.get(0).getNumer()+" "+clients.get(0).getDescryption()+"\n");

                }
            }

            return clients;
}
```

1:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ArrayList<CUSTOMER> to_sent= new ArrayList<CUSTOMER>();

    public void conn(View view)  {
    String type="login";
    Connect connect = new Connect(this, type);
    to_sent=connect.execute(domena,  DB_name, name, password, ip).get();
    }
 }
```

2:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ArrayList<CUSTOMER> to_sent= new ArrayList<CUSTOMER>();

    public void conn(View view)  {
    String type="login";
    Connect connect = new Connect(this, type);
    connect.execute(domena,  DB_name, name, password, ip).get();
    to_sent=connect.clients;
    }
 }
```

3:

```
    public void sent(View view) {
    String type="sent";
    Connect connect = new Connect(this, type);
    connect.clients=to_sent;
    connect.execute(domena,  DB_name, name, password, ip);


}
```

If he uses the first method, UI blocks and ProgresDialog can not be seen. The other one seems to me not correct, but it works correctly with ProgresDialog.
As simple as possible return ArrayList clients to Main Activity?
I need this Array to next button.

If I wrote something wrong, please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the entire point of an AsyncTask.  It does not return a value, because its executing in parallel.  If you were to wait until it was finished, there would be no point in using the AsyncTask at all.  Any code that needs to be done after the task finishes should be put in onPostExecute.

Comment: I know this but I have to use AsyncTask because I have a connection to the database and AndroidStudio reports an error if I do not use it.
If using 2 method and blocking UI with ProgresDialog. Is I getting the correct result by assigning an ArrayList from AsyncTask to ArrayList from Main?

Comment: @EksterminSir So you put all the code that needs to run after it finishes in onPostExecute.  You do not wait for it to finish-  ESPECIALLY not on the UI thread and ESPECIALLY not in onCreate which has a watchdog timer and can cause an ANR.

Comment: I have 2 butttons, first is **conect** after he load clients i want click second button **sent**, but if my connection error or dont finish i cant click **sent**

Comment: @EksterminSir then disable it until the connection finishes, show a loading UI, etc.  You cannot pause on the main thread like that-  at BEST it will be unresponsive, at worst you'll crash.  WHat's better-  a UI with a disabled button that you need to wait for, or a UI where NOTHING reacts because the main thread is held up?  Because that's what you'll have if you wait

Comment: That's why I want to use progresDialog to let the user see something happen and wait.
But I am not sure whether the assignment will always return a good value.

connect.execute (domain, DB_name, name, password, ip);
// there working ProgresDialog to finish doInBacgurand
     to_sent = connect.clients;